# Scala :: for comprehension and Either with free variables

Tags: scala, for-comprehension

I need to wrap up a bunch of functions that return `Either[String, X]` - into a for-comprehension, and also I need to transform the results of some invocations using some pure functions, and cache those results in the temporary variables.

The following (very artificial) code does not compile

```
1: def someFunc(x: Int): Either[String, Int] = Right(x)
2: 
3: def someMath(i: Int): Int = i
4: 
5: val z = for {
6:  x <- Right("aaaa").right
7:  y <- Right((1, x)).right
8:  tmp = someMath(y._1)
9:  t <- Right(tmp).right
A:  l <- someFunc(tmp).right
B: } yield l
C: 
D: z
```

> Error:(7, 6) value flatMap is not a member of Product with
>   Serializable with scala.util.Either[Nothing,((Int, String), Int)]   y
>   <- Right((1, x)).right
>       ^

How do I define a variable of an arbitrary type (not Either) in the `for {...}` expression?

Comment: I've reproduced this error under `scala-2.11.8`. But under `scala-2.12.1` it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

In scala 2.12, `Either` is a monadic type that can be composed using `for`, so the following works:

```
val z = for {
  x <- Right("aaa")
  y <- Right((1, x))
 ...
}
```

As @jdevelop mentioned in the comments, this doesn't work in 2.10 or 2.11

If your `Left` type is an exception, then `Try` is a good alternative.  If you need a portable version of `Either`, it would not be hard to write one, as annoying as that is.

Comment: There's no `flatMap` on Either in Scala 2.11

Comment: @jdevelop good point, I've always been able to use Try instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can have an implicit converter like this:

```scala
  implicit class EitherOps[A,B](val e: Either[A,B]) extends AnyVal {
    def flatMap[A1 >: A, B1](f: B => Either[A1, B1]): Either[A1, B1] = e.right.flatMap(f)
    def map[B1](f: B => B1): Either[A, B1] = e.right.map(f)
  }
```

to make Either right biased like in Scala 2.12+.
You should make it available only for Scala 2.11.
This way you can use the same for-comprehensive code you have in 2.12 in 2.11 too.